# Passing variables to another webserver

Tags: php

Is it possible to pass variables from one webserver to another using php? I need to be able to pass variables from a webhost to a local server for processing and I dont know if it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to communicate between the servers somehow. How you do that communication determines if, and how, you would pass data. (You can't generally pass actual variables, just the contents of them).

If, for instance, you were communicating with HTTP then you could pass the data in the query string of the URI, or in the body of a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

Post a web request to that server.
You can do that using curl and add header data or post data too.
Check [php curl manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Simple post request will also do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could do this.  The simplest way and most service oriented would be to make a "catcher" php script which will recieve the variables on the target server and then the local server can run:

```
file_get_contents('http://targetserver.com/catcher.php?var1=val1&var2=val2&var3=val3...');
```

also look into sockets and direct connections, FTP, and other ways to do it.